# turning multiple addresses into cordinates python3

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, nominatim

I have scrapped a website to get the addresses of multiple places and in my list i have the street address, zip/city and the state/country so 3 different columns, i am not able to figure out how to turn the addresses into coordinates. here is my code so far. it is from two different tries.

```
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    address_new = (street + ' ,' + zip + ' ,' + city)
    location = geolocator.geocode(address_new)
    if location:
        lat = location.latitude
        lon = location.longitude

    geolocator = Nominatim()
    with open("addresses", 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            location = geolocator.geocode(line)
            print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
```

Comment: Those look like sensible attempts. Don't they work? What output do you get? What does your input data look like?

Comment: And I tagged this Nominatim but on second thoughts maybe that should be geopy instead. Please can you edit the question to pick the right tags? Thanks!